# Why does ImagesService always return urls with ip 0.0.0.0 in development?

Tags: debugging, google-app-engine, ip-address

Does anybody know why ImagesService.getServingUrl() from Google App engine SDK (1.6.0) always returns 0.0.0.0 in url in development enviroment ? How can I change it ? Initially I thought it depends on binding IP for DevServer which I pass in "--address" parameters but it turns out it's not the case.

This is problem for me because I can't fetch image from http://0.0.0.0/ on Windows 7 machine. But I know it works on Mac.

Plus I'd like to be able to test my GWT app from another machine in the network therefore I'd like to bind to IP other than localhost.

Because of it I have to string.replace() "0.0.0.0" with my real ip which kinda lame :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit annoying, and I think that a lot of people have that same string-replace in their code.  I suspect that the GAE team have it as a low priority (rightly), because of its low impact and easy workaround.  Anyway, there is at least one open issue on their issue tracker:  http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4402

Here's another related issue:  http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5871
You might want to double-check that you aren't specifying (even accidentally) the ip address when starting up the development server.

Comment: I see. I posted new bug there. We'll see what they say.

Comment: GAE team has acknowledged the bug. Hopefully it will be fixed in future.

Answer (score 1):

i solved it by going  Edit->Application Settings and then remove all values from "External Command line flags"
[image: App En]